# Is it possible to have different publishing destinations depending on the configuration in visual studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, winforms, clickonce, publish

I have a Winforms application that deploys using ClickOnce. I have several customers for this application and I need to deploy it in each of them with different configurations and different destinations (publishing folders and installations folders). Also, I need to change things like the title of the publish, version numbers, etc.

The different configurations that have to do with the app.config are handled with pre-build events, replacing the app.config with different files depending on the configuration of the solution (debug, release, and other custom configurations). I also need to be able to change the publishing options based on the selected configuration.

Is this possible?

[image: This kind of thing I need to be able to change depending on the configuration]

Comment: Based on my research, currently clickonce doesn't support the functions like you said. Maybe you can request a feature about your problem in the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=8&entry=suggestion).